# asp.net core app build error - Access to the path Apex_POC.exe.config is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to build my ASP.NET core 1.0 application using .Net framework 4.6.1

But I am keep getting below error-

**Error                      Failed to make the following project runnable: Apex_POC (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) reason: Access to the path 'C:\perforce\CFA\Apex\POC\Apex_POC\src\Apex_POC\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\Apex_POC.exe.config' is denied.        Apex_POC             C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets          262**

I verified path is correct and make sure that none of folder/files are in read only mode.

Also, verified I can write into this file. The current content of file is below (everything is by default, nothing is added from my side)-

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
<gcServer enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

**How to resolve this issue?**

My environment is VS2015 Professional update3 and a Windows 7 machine.

Thanks & Regards

Vishal

Comment: Are you running the build under a different user account?

Comment: No Victor. using same account and VS is also running under admin mode.

Comment: Okay... Let see what else could cause this: (1) Do you have all the updates for Win 7 (SPs & stuff)? (2) Are you running multiple instance of VS or something like `dotnet watch` from a console? (3) Is the error consistent or sporadic?

Comment: (1) Yes, Windows 7 updated weekly basis. Even VS is also having latest updates. (2) I am running only single instance of VS2005 professional update3 in admin mode. Not using any console. (3) Error occurring consistently from today.

Comment: (1) Do you have any post build scripts? (2) Does it happen for any solution or just this one (aka, does it happen for a new project)? (3) Do you have any csproj projects in the solution?

Comment: (1)yes default post build scripts are there in project.json "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]  (2) I tried creating new projects with .net core and .net full VS templates and both worked fine. (3) No csproj only one xproj project

Comment: Since you mention that a new project works fine, I assume it's something that your project does that locks that file. Mind sharing the project structure and the project.json files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `app.config` file with the flag `gcserver`  in your root `ASP.NET Core MVC` project folder was part of `ASP.NET Core RC1` version where  a separate config file was used for some config settings including to  tell the runtime to perform garbage collection.

in RC2 this was moved to `project.json` and the flag name changed from  `gcserver` to `System.GC.Server`

if you create a default ASP.NET Core RTM template you will notice that in your `project.json` you have the garbage collection flag and you don't have an `app.config` file.

Your solution is to copy the following section to your `project.json` and then to delete the `app.config` file in your root project directory from Visual Studio.

```
"runtimeOptions": {
  "configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
  }
},
```

You can read more about the runtime configuration changes between RC1 and RC2 [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/v1.0.0-rc2/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md#runtimeoptions-section-runtimeconfigjson)

The different flag options [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md#host-configuration-knobs)

I can just guess the reason for the error is that in RTM they don't allow copying a `config` value to your bin directory when debugging anymore.

Comment: Thanks for lovely explanation. Removing app.config worked for me. However, I do have 2 questions- (1) It is working without adding GC block in project.json. Is this fine? (2) You are referring to **default ASP.NET Core RTM template**, Is this ASP.NET core 1.0 application template in VS2015 professional?

Comment: It will work fine without the Garbage Collection Block in `project.json`. If you have a deployed site in production you might want to add it as you might over time use more memory than it should without it. Yes in the default ASP.NET core 1.0 application template in VS2015 you get it as well.

Comment: I neither have a  `project.json` nor an `app.config`. More interestingly: the code compiles just fine under macOS. Why do Companies have to make this obscure und incompatible changes all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app.config` from your `.xproj` project and then try to build again.

Anything you want to add in `app.config`, you can either add it in `web.config` / `project.json` / `appsettings.json`

Similar issue is reported here-
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3419#ref-issue-158822811

Comment: I neither have a  `.xproj` nor an `app.config`.